# can not install docker-ce in AWS EC2 instance : Error: package: containerd.io (docker-ce-stable) Need: container SELinux

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, gpu

I was trying to install Docker on g4dnx4xlarge, which is a GPU instance.
Following the blog posted here [original blog](https://lambda-linux.io/blog/2016/07/06/baseimage-amzn-docker-base-image/), I could not get it run.
The error I got is:

```
Error: package: containerd.io -1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_ 64 (docker-ce-stable)
Need: container SELinux > = 2:2.74
You can try adding the -- skip broken option to solve this problem
You can try: RPM - VA -- nofiles -- nodigest
```

Could you please provide any hints here?

Thanks for any information you might provide.
Best,
Cassie

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing dependencies [from here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/):

```
sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch.rpm
```